# TFS: how to split the workbranch in two

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, version-control, branch

I am newbie in TFS, and actually we have an application having only one branch.

Supposing the changesets in the main/only branch actually are the following:

```
(no name)
===
AA0
AA1
AA2
AB0
AB1
AB2
```

I would like to separate the code in two branches:

```
Main  Beta
==========
AA0
AA1
AA2
...   AB0
...   AB1
...   AB2
...   ...
```

What steps I supposed to do?

Actually I created the branch "beta" from the latest version, and created another branch from the `AA2` changeset...
[image]

is it correct?

Comment: You can't retroactively branch changes.

Comment: @DanielMann what I am wondering is what I *can* do, rather what I can't... but it seems I can create a branch from a changeset... as in the picture...

Comment: Sure, you can create a branch based on a changeset. But the changes you made *after* that will still be on the original branch.

Comment: so there is any way to create a branch having the AB0...AB2 changes...

Comment: Merge the changes from Main to the dev branch, then revert the changesets in Main.

Comment: as I said, I already created the "beta" (dev) from the latest version, so I have no changes to merge...